# How to write the CharMatcher equivalent for the regex "word character"?

Tags: java, regex, guava

The regex `\w` matches exactly the characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, which is exactly what I need now.
I wonder if there's any simple way how to create a corresponding Guava's [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html).
I did the following (I don't like static imports):

```
private final static CharMatcher IDENTIFIER_CHAR = CharMatcher.is('_')
    .or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'))
    .or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z'))
    .or(CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9'))
    .precomputed();
```

There are a few predefined matchers, however something like

```
private final static CharMatcher IDENTIFIER_CHAR = CharMatcher.ASCII
    .and(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT)
    .or(CharMatcher.is('_'))
    .precomputed();
```

doesn't look any better. Neither does using `forPredicate` before we get [closures](http://java.dzone.com/news/java-8-lambda-syntax-closures) in Java 8.
There's no real problem here, it's just too verbose for something as simple and (I guess) as common.

Any nicer solution? Maybe did anybody implement something like `newRegexLikeCharMatcher("[A-Za-z0-9_]")`?

Comment: Your second option is basically what I'd use.  Remember, this cost should only be a thing once across your entire codebase.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: I wouldn't ask, if I was doing it once only. I've got a few similar patterns... but now I found out that I can reduce their number, so it's much better now. There's probably no reason to ask for a feature, but good enough for writing something myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implementation of your suggested method could be:

```
public CharMatcher newRegexLikeCharMatcher(String regex) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    return new CharMatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(char c) {
            return pattern.matcher(Character.toString(c)).find();
        }
    }.precomputed();
}
```

or

```
public CharMatcher newRegexLikeCharMatcher(String regex) {
    return CharMatcher.forPredicate(Predicates.compose(Predicates.containsPattern(regex), Functions.toStringFunction()))
            .precomputed();
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for something special, but given the way I stated my question I must accept your answer. Your solution has two small problems: 1. It also accepts patterns like `ab*|c+`. 2. It takes some time as the `Predicate` gets evaluated 2**16 times. For my my use case this doesn't matter at all. Moreover, if needed it could easily be optimized for simple patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this trivial method, which gets used a couple of times and makes it all a bit nicer:

```
private static CharMatcher inRanges(char startInclusive, char endInclusive, char... chars) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument((chars.length & 1) == 0, "The chars must come in pairs");
    CharMatcher result = CharMatcher.inRange(startInclusive, endInclusive);
    for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i+=2) result = result.or(CharMatcher.inRange(chars[i], chars[i+1]));
    return result;
}
```

I'm afraid such cases as mine are not common enough and every user can make the solution for their special case just like I did...

---

I found my above solution still impractical (too much apostrophes to type) and created this trivial method instead

```
public static CharMatcher newRegexLikeCharMatcher(String s) {
    CharMatcher result = CharMatcher.NONE;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i) {
        if (i+2 < s.length() && s.charAt(i+1) == '-') {
            result = result.or(CharMatcher.inRange(s.charAt(i), s.charAt(i+2)));
            i += 2;
        } else {
            result = result.or(CharMatcher.is(s.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Whenever it encounters a "char-dash-char" triplet, it interprets it as a range, otherwise it adds a single matching character (so leading and trailing dashes are interpreted literally, even strange things like `-a-b-` and `a-b-c` work).